# Unable to add bullets before post title on WP

Tags: php, css, wordpress

How to add square bullets before post title [generated by flexible recent post (frp) WP plugin] on different categories like health, entertainment, etc on my site lagatar dot com

Plugin shortcode: `frp_title` `frp_link`

Here's the css copy of frp:

http://lagatar.com/copyof-frp-front.css

http://lagatar.com/copyof-frp-admin.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the post headings are in a list format (like in a navigation list) go with the `list-style` method. But if the post headings are actual heading elements, go with the CSS `:before` method.

## List-Styles

You can style your `ul` elements with the `list-style` CSS property.

### Resource

[CSS-Tricks: list-style](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/)

### Example

```css
.frp-widget {
 list-style-type: square;
 list-style-position: outside;
 list-style-image: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="frp-widget">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>  
</ul>
```

---

## CSS :before Property

You can style your `h[0-9]` elements with the `:before` CSS selector.

### Resource

[HTML Entity Codes](http://timtrott.co.uk/html-entity-codes-ascii-unicode-symbols/)

### Example

```css
h2:before {
    content: "\25A0";
}
```

```html
<h2>Example Post Heading</h2>
```

Comment: where should i add this ul in frp's css file? @HandyDan have a look at http://lagatar.com

Comment: The maintainability to this default CSS is pretty bad... for this very reason CSS declarations should never be too specific... For our CSS to work you would need to add 
`.block-type-widget-area li.widget ul.frp-widget { list-style-type: square; list-style-position: outside; list-style-image: none; }` to your "copyof-frp-front.css" file
and then remove `.frp-widget .frp-news { list-style: none; }`

Comment: just changing already present list-style-type: none; to 'square' worked. now how can i increase it's size and change color to like red. @HandyDan

Comment: You should check out the CSS Tricks resource I mentioned. If you want to change the color add `color: red;` to the CSS declaration: `.block-type-widget-area li.widget ul.frp-widget`

Comment: `.frp-widget .frp-news {
    list-style-image: url('liststyle.gif');

    margin-bottom: 10px;
}` custom image not appearing why? @HandyDan

Answer (score 0):

What does the HTML look like?

Use Google Chrome inspector or browser developer tool of choice to find the class, ID, or relationship to other elements of the title, and do something like this:

```
.page-title:before { 
   content: "\25AA"
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://lagatar.com and tell me where should i add the bullet css... @zep_fan

Comment: h2.entry-title:before { content: "\25AA" }